# Selenium PageObject throws Invocation Target Exception

Tags: java, selenium, testng, page-factory

I am trying to create a framework(Selenium+TestNg+java) for a Web app(The environment is MacOs+ChromeDriver and the driver server is in \usr\local\bin) but got stuck in basic structure. I have a class(Driversetup.java) that starts the browser, another one that contains WebElements and methods(ProfileUpdateObjects.java) and the third one containing test methods. Now, when I try to run this TestNG class having just a single method, I get following exception.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory.instantiatePage(PageFactory.java:138).
```

Below is the code (All the classes are in different packages).

```
public class ProfileUpdateTest {

    @Test(enabled = true, priority = 1)
    public void profileUpdate() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException, ParseException {
        WebDriver driver = DriverSetup.startBrowser("chrome");
        ProfileUpdateObjects pu = PageFactory.initElements(driver, ProfileUpdateObjects.class);
        pu.navigateProfile();
    }
}
```

The code for ProfileUpdateObject class

```
public class ProfileUpdateObjects {
    WebDriver driver;

    public ProfileUpdateObjects(WebDriver cdriver) {
        this.driver = cdriver;
    }

    @FindBy(xpath = " //div[@class='ico-menu']")
    private WebElement menu;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//a[@title='My Dashboard']")
    private WebElement myDashboard;

    @FindBy(xpath = " //a[contains(text(),'View Profile')]")
    public WebElement profile;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//li[contains(text(),'Permanent Address')]")
    private WebElement permanentAddress;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//li[contains(text(),'Banking Information')]")
    private WebElement bankingInformation;

    WebDriverWait waitfor = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2000);

    public void navigateProfile() throws InterruptedException {
        menu.click();
        profile.click();
        waitfor.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(permanentAddress));
    }
}
```

DriverSetup.java

```
public class DriverSetup {
    public static WebDriver driver;

    public static WebDriver startBrowser(String browserName, String url) {
        if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(url);
        return driver;
    }
}
```

It is failing in pu.navigateProfile() call. Also, is it true that @FindBy takes more memory compared to driver.find() syntax and besides POM are there any other design principles for Automation framework because most of the resources over Web are one or the other implementation of POM.

Comment: `startBrowser` method acceps 2 arguments. "browserName" and "url" but you provided only "browseName" in `profileUpdate()` test.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to move `new WebDriverWait`. It should not be instantiated as instance variable.

Instead of:

```
WebDriverWait waitfor = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2000);

    public void navigateProfile() throws InterruptedException {
        menu.click();
        profile.click();
        waitfor.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(permanentAddress));
    }
```

Use:

```
    public void navigateProfile() {
        menu.click();
        profile.click();
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 2000).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(permanentAddress));
    }
```

This will solve your issue (Already tested it)